# How can I sort lines in Geany?

Tags: geany

I was looking for a way to sort lines in Geany.

Then found the solution below.

Answer (score 46):

I found the answer on http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=24607

- From the menu bar, select `Edit` - `Format` - `Send Selection to` - `Set Custom Commands`.
- Click the `Add` button in the `Set Custom Commands` window.
- Enter `sort` in the command field, enter `sort` or a name to your liking in the label field, and then click the `OK` button.
- Select the text that you want to sort.
- Right-click on the selected text and select `Format` - `Send Selection to` - `sort` to sort the selected text.

Comment: Great answer :)

Comment: This works perfectly on Ubuntu and Windows but not on CentOS.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Error 400. We're sorry, but we could not fulfill your request for /forums/viewtopic.php?id=24607 on this server."*

Comment: This answer does not work (which is ***very clear*** if you try to follow the instructions in it). Can you update your answer?

Comment: From a now deleted answer (that should have been a comment): "The steps described here are ***not*** sufficient. You ***must*** also enter something in the "Label" field associated with the Command. In other words, in step 3, enter "sort" in the command field, click on the "Label" field and enter "sort" or a name to your liking. Unfortunately, Geany will just ***ignore*** what you enter in the Command field if you forget to put something in the Label field. IMHO, it is a poor user interface. Hopefully it will be fixed in the future."